# Django StreamHttpRequest running multiple cameras

Tags: django, opencv

I am building an app using OpenCV and Django with multiple cameras attached. I plan to create a preview feature that will allow you to open one camera after another to check their focus. However, I have tried with `streamhttpresponse` and have not been able to find a way to close the stream manually, in which case even if I close the window and try to open another camera, it always fails. I will have to refresh the webpage and open a new camera.

The question is, can I turn off the streaming response? Alternatively, create a new response that can somehow replace the existing one.

I hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend taking django out of the situation (or any web stuff). just use OpenCV's `imshow` and handle key presses returned from `waitKey`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for response! Unfortunately I try to build the webapp and django is used as the backend to communicate to the frontend side. How I might skip Django? Totally understand that doing it through the raw opencv way locally would work.